# Why Android Softkeyboard hides the bottom most TextView?

Tags: android

This is the layout file of my Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- android:fillViewport="true" -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chatDispWindow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chatTypeWindow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage|textNoSuggestions"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
    <!-- android:hint="@string/groupChatDispMsg" -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chatStatusWindow"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chatTypeWindow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/send_chatbtn_selector"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sendLbl" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chatTypeWindow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chatStatusWindow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_selector"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/sendChatImeBtn"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/sendLbl"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="45dp" />
    <!-- android:hint="@string/chatWindowMsg" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatStatusWindow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp" />
    <!-- android:text="@string/chatStatusMsg" -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the behaviour of the App now...

[image: Default View]
[image: Ui When User clicks on the EditText]

Problem is the keyboard hides the bottom most TextView of the Screen, **How can I make that visible even if the Keyboard is showing ?**

I have tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but its not working. please help,

**EDIT**
After further digging in I came to know that if I remove the Full Screen Theme then `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` works perfectly. How I can get that with FullScreen Theme ?

Comment: I got exactly the same issue, does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and removed the `full screen theme` from this Activity as i found that its a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497) of android. They claim that it is solved however it was not at least not on the devices I tested my code.

I hope this answer can be useful for someone visiting this thread in future and can save their time and energy. Thanks everyone,

Comment: Thank you, it works very well and just saved me lot of time ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this in manifest file under your activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```